# Redirect script output to /dev/tty1 and also capture output to file

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection, tty, tee

I want to display text output on the console that is always displayed on a small screen on my Raspberry Pi.

The following code works for showing that text output:

```
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /dev/tty1
```

Now I want to capture the output in parallel with seeing it on the screen - I have tried 'tee' but that does not show text on the screen and also does not capture it to file:

```
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py | tee /dev/tty1 /tmp/capture.txt
```

How can I redirect the output of my script to `/dev/tty1` so I can see it on my screen but also capture the output to file?

UPDATE 1:

Per the answer below - I tried using 'script' - unfortunately it did not work:

```
script -c "cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /dev/tty1" /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html
```

UPDATE 2:

I also tried to 'tail' the output of the file that I redirected the output to into /dev/tty1, but it also did not work:

```
sudo tail -F /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html > /dev/tty1 &
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html
```

Comment: Weird. Does `tee /tmp/capture.txt >/dev/tty1` work?

Comment: Nope :( , this doesn't work either: /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py | tee /tmp/capture.txt > /dev/tty1

Comment: Ok - so where is your output going then? Are you not writing to stdout? Do you `open()` a descriptor in your script and write to it? `tee` will only `tee` its stdin. If you can figure out where you are writing then you can dup it. What is up with all of the `sudo nice` stuff? You can just tail `/dev/vcs1` if you must, but you're doing some weird stuff. Can you drop all of the `sudo` stuff and still print?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the standard output? .../test_wrapper.py 1>/dev/tty1 1>/path/to/file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the input, it did not work for Python scripts because it was buffering the output.

This allows it to work with tee:

```
python -u ./myscript.py | tee /dev/tty1 /tmp/a.txt
```

Comment: This just solves the problem for a python script output. @Robert Jacobs answer is more genral and seems to be the real answer to your question (which was not specific about python).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to save the output of a command, use the script command

```
script -c "your command" /tmp/capture.txt
```

The output will be sent to the tty and also to capture.txt

If tty1 is not the console that you are running from, you could run a

```
tail -F /tmp/capture.txt
```

from that tty in order to get the results there as well.

Comment: Hi Robert - thanks for the input. I tried launching this over an SSH terminal: script -c "cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /dev/tty1" /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html

Comment: However, the text that is redirected to /dev/tty1 does not get captured in the /tmp/capture.txt file. Only errors if I kill the process. Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't redirect to /dev/tty, redirect to /tmp/capture. Then try tail -F /tmp/capture > /dev/tty1 & . Start the tail first in background. and kill when done.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it had the same effect. /dev/tty1 must be special?

Comment: Check to see if you have permission to write to the tty. "ls -l /dev/tty1". Fix permission if required.

Comment: Try : script -c "script -c 'your command /dev/tty1' /tmp/capture "

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the question was not just about python scripts.